# Can I simply unzip war file and copy it in my server directory?

Tags: java, web-services

This may be a simple question.
I have a simple app which I am deploying using winstone as a web server

```
java -jar winstone-0.9.10.jar --httpPort=8081 --warfile=mywarFile.war
```

Could I simply unzip the files in the war file and manually copy them in my server directory structure? Doing that is not working, why? What else do I need to do?

Thank you in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0):

From the Winstone page, http://winstone.sourceforge.net:

```
  java -jar target/winstone-0.9.10.jar --webroot=<location of webroot> (+ other options)

- OR -
  java -jar target/winstone-0.9.10.jar --warfile=<location of warfile> (+ other options)

- OR -
  java -jar target/winstone-0.9.10.jar --webappsDir=<location of webapps directory> (+ other options)

- OR -
  java -jar target/winstone-0.9.10.jar --hostsDir=<location of hosts directory> (+ other options)
```

Comment: I do not want to use winstone, that is my question. Can I simply copy all the files into the web directory of my server without using winstone? How do I do that? I tried unzipping the war file, copy all the files, but I am getting some errors.

Comment: Q: What are you going to do with the WAR files once you unzip them???  Run your web app in a *different* J2EE container (like Tomcat or JBoss)?   What exactly are you trying to accompllsh??? What exactly "isn't working"?  Be specific.

Comment: Thank you for your answer and patience. Yes, I would like to know if I can run it in a different J2EE container. I might be getting the implementation of that wrong, and I understand I am not being clear, I am sorry, I don't have much experience with it.

Comment: Many containers require an explicit "deploy war" procedure.  Others (like Tomcat and JBoss), support "automatic deploys" you can simply drag/drop the war into a "deploy" folder.  Q: What's your App server?  Q: What specific problems are you encountering?